# Daily realized volatility and true daily volatility

Tags: volatility, time-series, high-frequency

Can someone help if I am thinking correctly?
If $R(t,i)$ is the i'th log-return for $i = 1\ldots,M$ of day $t$ for $t = 1\ldots,T$.

Can I assume that the daily realized volatility (denoted $RV(t)$) is a consistent estimator of the true daily volatility
denoted $QV(t)$] in the sense that $RV(t)\rightarrow QV(t)$ when $T\rightarrow\infty$ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To keep it brief:** *the realized variance estimator, $RV_t$, is only a consistent estimator of Quadratic Variation (QV) under absence of microstructure noise.*

Following the paper of **[Barndorff‐Nielsen, O. E., & Shephard, N. (2002)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3088799?seq=1)** they show how the realized variance estimator,
$$
RV_t = \sum_{i=1}^n r_{i,t}^2,
$$
**is a consistent estimator of QV under absence of microstructure noise**, when the number of intraday observations goes to infinity:

$$
RV_t = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n r_{i,t}^2  \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\longrightarrow} QV_t.
$$

---

In their setup they model the log-price process following a diffusion on the form:

$$
dp_t = (\mu + \beta \sigma^2_t) \: dt + \sigma_t dW_t, 
$$

where $\mu$ is the drift and $\beta$ is the risk-premium. Following from the diffusion setup of the log-price process, the quadratic variation $QV_t$ of the log-returns can be described as:

$$
QV_t = \int_{t-1}^t \sigma^2_s \: ds,
$$
which is equivalent to the integrated volatility/variance $IV_t = \int_{t-1}^t \sigma^2_s \: ds$ (*only under a diffusion process, see paper*).

---

##### I have highlighted some key findings from the above paper:

1. $RV_t$ is also an unbiased estimator when $\mu = \beta = 0$.
2. In practice, the effect of $\mu$ and $\beta$ on realized volatility/variance, is extremely small and is often safe to ignore in many cases (*See section 5 of above paper*).
3. Under the diffusion setting, when $\mu = \beta = 0$, and assuming absence of noise, $RV_t$ is a consistent estimator of Integrated variance/volatility $IV_t$:
   $$
   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}RV_t  \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\longrightarrow} QV_t = \int_{t-1}^t \sigma^2_s \: ds.
   $$
4. Avoiding microstructure noise can be done by sparse-sampling intraday observations.

---

As a last note **[Zhang, L., Mykland, P. A., & Aït-Sahalia, Y. (2005)](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Emykland/paperlinks/p1394.pdf)** show that when microstructure noise is present, the bias of the $RV_t$ grows with $n$ and thus explodes when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thus the realized volatility estimates not the true integrated volatility/variance, but rather a noise contaminated counterpart.

Comment: very nice and coherent answer!

Comment: It is a great help and mow I get it clearly.